# Exception Class request does not exists in index.php

Tags: php, laravel

i have uploaded my laravel project to live server but its not working  when i track code i get the execption that class request does not exists,please help me to find out the error
this is my file
index.php

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
$app->bind('path.public', function() {

    return __DIR__;

});

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

try{
$request = App\Http\Request::capture()
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo "error:".$e->getMessage()."<br>";
}

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = App\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Do a composer update. Most likely vendor files were not uploaded properly or the paths are different.

Comment: @Andrew but its working fine in local server

Comment: So what's your point?

Comment: in index.php code throws exception that class request does not exists

Comment: Again, what's your point? We're talking about 2 different environments here. Do a composer update on your remote server and see if that clears the issue.

Comment: i want to say $app  get the value but                                               
 $response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = App\Http\Request::capture()
); makes an error on live server

Comment: Just do a composer dump-autoload on live server. Andrew is right

Comment: thanks for reply i will try it

Comment: maybe php artisan clear:cache will do something

Comment: do a composer update. and run these too
php artisan config:clear ,
php artisan cache:clear , 
php artisan module:optimize,
php artisan optimize,
composer dump-autoload

Comment: Do you have App\Http\Request class? The Request class ususally lives in a diffferent namespace.

Answer (score 0):

**Request** facade usually lives in a different namespace. Try replacing any reference to

```
App\Http\Request
```

with just

```
Request
```

in order to access the facade by its global namespace alias.